# FFmpeg eats all the memory and crash within a minute while recording chrome activity

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, out-of-memory, alsa

I'm using ffmpeg to capture the activity of chrome (thanks to chrome driver) and record it into an mp4 file. However, the memory consumed by ffmpeg is quickly blowing up, and after a minute or so my 8GB of memory get saturated and I have to reboot the PC.

Unbuntu 16.0
ALSA loopback (installed by modprobe snd-aloop)
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.york0

This is the command line to ffmpeg:

```
    ffmpeg -y -v info -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -r 30 -s 1280x720 -thread_queue_size 4096 
-i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -thread_queue_size 4096 -i plug:cloop -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100 
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 
-crf 25 -g 60 -tune zerolatency -f mp4 file.mp4
```

If I remove all the sound input (-i plug:cloop -acodec aac -strict -2 -ar 44100) then the memory is OK, stable, but the file generated can't be played with VLC or media player.

The logs from ffmpeg looks normal to me:

```
root$ ffmpeg -rtbufsize 15M -y -v info -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -r 30 -s 1280x720 -thread_queue_size 4096 -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -thread_queue_size 4096 -i hw:0 -acodec ac3_fixed -strict -2 -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -profile:v main -level 3.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 25 -g 60 -tune zerolatency -f mp4 /tmp/recordings/stuff.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, x11grab, from ':0.0+0,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1587042601.295126, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, alsa, from 'hw:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1587042601.304179, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] profile Main, level 3.1
Output #0, mpegts, to '/tmp/recordings/stuff.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 (ac3_fixed), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 ac3_fixed
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> ac3 (ac3_fixed))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    7 fps=0.0 q=21.0 size=       5kB time=00:00:00.23 bitrate= 180.5kbits/s frame=   15 fps= 15 q=21.0 size=      15kB time=00:00:00.50 bitrate= 240.6kbits/s frame=   21 fps= 14 q=21.0 size=      21kB time=00:00:00.70 bitrate= 249.2kbits/s frame=   28 fps= 14 q=21.0 size=      28kB time=00:00:00.93 bitrate= 246.5kbits/s frame=   35 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=      35kB time=00:00:01.16 bitrate= 244.9kbits/s frame=   42 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=      44kB time=00:00:01.40 bitrate= 260.0kbits/s frame=   49 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=      51kB time=00:00:01.63 bitrate= 256.9kbits/s frame=   56 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=      58kB time=00:00:01.86 bitrate= 254.6kbits/s frame=   63 fps= 13 q=22.0 size=      66kB time=00:00:02.10 bitrate= 255.7kbits/s frame=   70 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=      75kB time=00:00:02.33 bitrate= 263.0kbits/s frame=   77 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=      82kB time=00:00:02.56 bitrate= 261.3kbits/s frame=   79 fps= 13 q=21.0 Lsize=      85kB time=00:00:02.63 bitrate= 264.4kbits/s
video:8kB audio:61kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 22.604090%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] frame I:2     Avg QP: 5.10  size:   760
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] frame P:77    Avg QP: 6.78  size:    88
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] mb I  I16..4: 99.9%  0.0%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:100.0%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 91%  0%  9%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  0%  0% 100%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 98%  2%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x928ee0] kb/s:25.23
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

This is my .asoundrc file.

```
# playback PCM device: using loopback subdevice 0,0
pcm.amix {
  type dmix
  ipc_key 219345
  slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,0"
}

# capture PCM device: using loopback subdevice 0,1
pcm.asnoop {
  type dsnoop
  ipc_key 219346
  slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,0,1"
}

# duplex device combining our PCM devices defined above
pcm.aduplex {
  type asym
  playback.pcm "amix"
  capture.pcm "asnoop"
}

# ------------------------------------------------------
# for jack alsa_in and alsa_out: looped-back signal at other ends
pcm.ploop {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,1,1"
}

pcm.cloop {
  type dsnoop
  ipc_key 219348
  slave.pcm "hw:Loopback,1,0"
}

# ------------------------------------------------------
# default device

pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "aduplex"
}
```

I'm not sure how to debug this kind of issue, any idea why the memory blow up so fast like that ?

Comment: FFmpeg 2.8 is ancient. Get a build from the current git master branch and try again before doing anything else. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (not sure if it has ALSA support) or follow a [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to ffmpeg 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 (via repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4) and I still get the same memory issue.

Comment: Your command and log don't match. What's the minimal command that still causes the memory problem?